# Neo4j in high availability mode in Java embedded

Tags: java, neo4j, high-availability

Is it possible to run Neo4j in high availability (HA) mode with read/write access of multiple java clients(java embedded)?

If yes are there special configurations needed?
(Additionally to the standard HA configurations)

I want to run a HA cluster containing three servers local on my computer. Writing and reading from three java clients using sockets.

Comment: Removed the "thanks", removed abbrev from title, add abbrev detail in body at first mentioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running a Neo4j cluster is perfectly possible in embedded mode. You can even mix server instances and embedded instances in the same cluster.

For a embedded cluster instance be sure to use [HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.html) and pass in your config options. At least you need:

```
`ha.initial_hosts`
`ha.server_id`
```

In the same way you would do it in a server instance in neo4j.properties file.

Comment: Thank you alot.  If I use read in of the two configuration files from Java,  I do need to configuration something  additionally?

Comment: depends on your setup. In most cases these two will be good enough to have a basic cluster configuration.

Comment: I am starting the three HA Clusters on my local computer - using HighAvailabilityFactory and the configs from the HAGuide.  But it seems like the Servers do not interact. When I am executing queries on them?

Comment: do you have all instances listed in `ha.initial_hosts` ? Are they on the same subnet?